# Collapse directories in zsh prompt

Tags: regex, perl, zsh

I am using the following function to generate my `zsh prompt`:

```
_sudar_collapsed_wd() {
  echo $(pwd | perl -pe "
   BEGIN {
      binmode STDIN,  ':encoding(UTF-8)';
      binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
   }; s|^$HOME|~|g; s|/([^/])[^/]*(?=/)|/\$1|g
")
}
```

Basically this converts a path like `/Users/sudar/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` into `~/D/c/d/d/d/dir4` by collapsing all parent directories except the current one.

But I don't want to collapse the last 3 directories in the path. So `/Users/sudar/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4` becomes `~/D/c/d/dir2/dir3/dir4`

The actual substitution happens in this regular expression:  `s|/([^/])[^/]*(?=/)|/\$1|g`.

How to change this regular expression, so that it doesn't substitute the last 3 directories in the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this,

```
s|^$HOME|~|g; s|/([^/])[^/]*(?=/[^/]*/[^/]*/)|/\$1|g
```

It checks that the match must be followed by atleast three forward slashes.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zN9sQ2/5)